# Pop-up menu in Eclipse gets shrunk

Tags: eclipse-juno, eclipse-plugin

I have a problem with the context menu in Eclipse Juno. I have a class extending the `ContributionItem` class. This creates menu items. Each menu item has an index. But I don't know, what value have the index to contain and how should it behave. I suppose, that it should insert items on the position. E.g. I have contribution URI:

```
popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer?before=common.new.menu
```

Then is my `fill(Menu menu, int index)` method invoked with 0 as index, because `common.new.menu` is the first item. But always the **New** menu item (which is the firs one in the pop-up menu) disappears and when I'm right-clicking second time, the pop-up menu gets shrunk and contains separators and few items (including my items) only. I'm totally lost...

Note: When a resource has been clicked, the `fill()` method is always called twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heureka! Googling for a long time have I found it. Somebody noted in one discusion, that there is also important to override the `isDynamic()` method defined in `ContributionItem` class. The default implementation always returns false. In Indigo it usually does not matter, but Juno is a bit stricter. In own contribution item is necessary to override the `isDynamic()` method to make it returning always true.